# Android active download threads

Tags: android, multithreading, download

I am using the following code for downloading file from server:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
urlConnection.connect();


StorageTools.maintainMemoryEmptyThreshold(25);
if (tempFolderFile.createNewFile()) {
    tempFolderFile.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(tempFolderFile);
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
int downloadedSize = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
int bufferLength = 0;
while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    LOGGER.debug("Progress: downloadedSize: " + downloadedSize + "totalSize: " + totalSize);
}

fileOutput.close();
if (downloadedSize == totalSize) {
    LOGGER.info("Downloaded at " + tempFolderFile.getAbsolutePath());
    StorageTools.moveFile(tempFolder, targetFolder, fileName);
    return true;
}
```

I trigger the download using a new thread into a tempfolder, move it into required folder upon download completion. How to maintain a cap on the number of active download threads and add remaining downloads to a queue ?

Also, following are my concerns in this regard:

1. Is there any way in which I can incorporate a threadpool executor for queuing downloads using above function ?
2. Does the buffersize impact the download speed ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html
2. buffersize will not impact much. I think it should be in safe limit.